# Dropdown list won't close after link triggering action is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a input field which opens a list of suggestions (live) when typing. A javascript function, returning the results to a div as a dropdown list.

Each item in this dropdown list is a href link which triggers an action. This action is also a javascript function.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="getObject(\'index\')">Item name</a></li>
    <li> ... other items ... </li>
    ....
</ul>
```

So far ok, works fine.

Problem: the dropdown list stays open after clicking an item. I searched and tried a few dozen similar solutions, but I just can't get it to close.

This is the action which is triggered with when item in the list is clicked. Passing the value "q".

(To simplify the question here, I added an alert instead of the actual function I'll be using.q)

```
if(typeof $=='undefined') {
    function $(q) {
        return(document.getElementById(q));
    }
}

function getObject(q) {
    alert(q);
    /// close dropdown list here
};
```

Any help is highly appreciated ! I've been searching and trying similar codes for days now. Thanks!

This is the function triggering the drop down list

```
function showSearch(str){
if (str.length==0){ 
        document.getElementById("resultlist").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("resultlist").style.border="0px";
    return;
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("resultlist").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("resultlist").style.border="1px solid #CCCCCC";
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

The search.php looks up a mysql table with a simple select statement.

Comment: Would you mind showing the code you use for your dropdown? Also, you could add event listeners to the <a> tags instead of inline functions, which you should avoid.

Comment: Thanks Adrián. I added the code for the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

With the info avaible I supose the best solution is to set an id to the ul and then hide it with

```
$('#the_ul_id').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, Iñaki. I tried this code before. No success. I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hide' of null". Even though I have jquery included.

Answer (score 0):

I got it ! I'm using css styles to display, or not to display. The "hide" tip of Jeremy and Iñaki gave me the idea... Thanks! And thanks to Adrián for the hint about avoiding inline functions.

Here's the code for anyone having a similar issue

The input field and the div containing the drop down list:

```
<form><input type="text" class="searchfield" placeholder="Search" onKeyUp="showSearch(this.value)"></form>
<div id="resultlist"></div>
```

The function triggered when entering a search. It will display a drop down menu with items as links:

```
function showSearch(str)
{

// this will reset the css display value so a new search is displayed
var listShow = document.querySelector("#resultlist");
listShow.style.display = "inherit";


if (str.length==0)
{

document.getElementById("resultlist").innerHTML="";
document.getElementById("resultlist").style.border="0px";
return;
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("resultlist").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("resultlist").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();


}
```

The search.php will select query a mysql table and return the results as an ul / li list.
$indx is the unique item id and is passed on to be "q".

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="getObject(\'' . $indx . '\')">Item name</a></li>
<li> ... other items ... </li>
....
</ul>
```

The function triggered when clicking on an item in the displayed list:

```
function getObject(q) {

// does something here with the value q

// this lets the drop down list disappear after click on an item
var listHide = document.querySelector("#resultlist");
listHide.style.display = "none";

};
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery (your tags say jQuery), you can add event listeners trough the 'on' method, like this `$(element).on('click', function(){});` which is a better way of handling javaScript outside HTML.